# "plutusV2MintingPolicy" lookup not found by "balanceTx"

Tags: plutus, minting

I am trying to mint some example tokens in offchain plutus code on tag `v1.0.0-alpha1`.

This is the OffChain code I am currently using:

```
mintFactoryToken :: Contract () MintFactorySchema Text ()
mintFactoryToken = do
  outRef <- getUnspentOutput
  pkh    <- ownFirstPaymentPubKeyHash
  o      <- fromJust <$> unspentTxOutFromRef outRef
  let
    !policy     = mintValidator outRef
    symbol     = scriptCurrencySymbol policy
    mintValue  = Value.singleton symbol contractDataTokenName 1 <> Value.singleton symbol chunkCreationTokenName 1
  Contract.logDebug outRef
  Contract.logDebug policy
  Contract.logDebug symbol
  Contract.logDebug mintValue
  let
    l          = Constraints.plutusV2MintingPolicy policy <>
                 Constraints.unspentOutputs (Map.singleton outRef o)
    constr     = Constraints.mustMintValue mintValue
  unbalanced <- Contract.mkTxConstraints @Any l constr
  Contract.logDebug @Text "Unbalanced"
  adjusted  <- Contract.adjustUnbalancedTx unbalanced
  Contract.logDebug @Text "adjusted"
  unsigned  <- Contract.balanceTx adjusted
  Contract.logDebug @Text "unsigned"
  signed    <- Contract.submitBalancedTx unsigned
  Contract.logDebug @Text "signed"
  --ledgerTx <- Contract.submitTxConstraintsWith @Void l constr
  Contract.awaitTxConfirmed $ getCardanoTxId signed
  Contract.logDebug @Text "signed"
```

But as soon as it reaches `Contract.balanceTx adjusted` I encounter the following error:

```
Slot 00001: *** CONTRACT STOPPED WITH ERROR: "\"WalletContractError (ValidationError (CardanoLedgerValidationError \\\"MissingScript (RdmrPtr Mint 0) (fromList [(RdmrPtr Mint 0,(Minting (PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash \\\\\\\"2fcc3c79d2cb27a9784a7d3e69de5f1909406fcbc33567e6dd24288b\\\\\\\"}),Nothing,ScriptHash \\\\\\\"2fcc3c79d2cb27a9784a7d3e69de5f1909406fcbc33567e6dd24288b\\\\\\\"))])\\\"))\""
```

Do I have to do something special in order to get this to work or is this just not supported at the moment?

I've seen in the [Relese Notes](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/releases/tag/v1.0.0-alpha1) that some custom validation rules are used at the moment:

> ...
>
> - `plutus-contract` emulator has been updated to work with Babbage era types. However, the UTxO index in the emulator does not support transaction outputs with reference scripts and inline datums.
> - `plutus-contract` emulator uses the Babbage era validation rules from cardano-ledger. However, we continue to use our old custom validation rules which we plan to remove in the next alpha release in order to fully commit with cardano-ledger 's validation rules.
>
> ...

But I am not sure if this causes my problem or not.

Signatures of the OnChain code:

```
{-# INLINABLE validateMinting #-}
validateMinting :: TxOutRef -> BuiltinData -> BuiltinData -> ()
...

mintValidator :: TxOutRef -> MintingPolicy
mintValidator oRef = mkMintingPolicyScript
   ($$(Tx.compile [|| validateMinting ||]) `Tx.applyCode` Tx.liftCode oRef)

mintCurrencySymbol :: TxOutRef -> CurrencySymbol
mintCurrencySymbol = scriptCurrencySymbol . mintValidator
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with what you're doing. A lot has changed since `v1.0.0-alpha1` so could you try with latest from `next-node` branch and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As james noted in a comment a simple update to the head of `next-node` resolved the issue. now tokens are minted correctly